# memcmp difference between gcc 10.3 and gcc 11.1 for char16_t

Tags: gcc, memcmp, char16-t

Im converting some tests that use the memcmp function and don't get the expected output. Now I've been trying to figure out why there is a difference in the windows vs linux output and I ended up on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/). There I played around with different gcc versions and to my surprise there is a difference between `x86-64 gcc 10.3` and `x86-64 gcc 11.1`. Can you help me figure out what the correct output is?

The code that is used:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
      char16_t const * p10 = u"Same";
      char16_t const * p210 = u"NotSame";
      auto result10 = memcmp(p10, p210, sizeof(p10));
      std::cout << result10 << "\n";

      char16_t const p11[] = u"Same";
      char16_t const p211[] = u"NotSame";
      auto result11 = memcmp(&p11, &p211, sizeof(p11));
      std::cout << result11 << "\n";
}
```

Gcc 10.3 output

```
5
5
```

Gcc 11.1 output

```
5
1
```

VS 2019 / MSVC 14.29.30133 output

```
1
1
```

It looks like in this example MSVC always returns exactly 1. For gcc this isnt the case sometimes, because it seems like it will return the difference. So between `83'S'` and `78'N'` is 5 so that is returned. Now my question is, is this the correct output or should it just be "1" in this case to indicate that there is a difference and ptr1 is higher than ptr2? I looked at [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) but its a bit vague as to what it should be.

Comment: What's the "expected output"? The documentation says the return value is zero when equal, and positive or negative when different, so 5 and 1 are equivalent here.

Comment: I know, but whats strange to me that there is a difference. Why is that?

Comment: The [difference](https://godbolt.org/z/hnPdeMb9c) between gcc 10.3 and 11.1 is because 11.1 could completely optimize the 2nd call of `memcmp` away and replaced it with just `1`. And MSVC has its own implementation of `memcmp`.